# Select multiple ID's - Both checkboxes must be selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way for two or more ID's be required to be checked before doing something.

For instance:

If **BOTH** Checkbox 1 and Checkbox 2 are checked then the event happens.

But if only 1 or the other are checked by themselves, something else happens.

I thought this would work but nope.

```
function toggleStatus() {
    if ($('#checkbox1 #checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
$('.option1 :input').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
$('.option1 :input').attr('checked', false);
}

function toggleStatus() {
    if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
$('.option2 :input').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
$('.option2 :input').attr('checked', false);
}

function toggleStatus() {
    if ($('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
$('.option3 :input').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
$('.option3 :input').attr('checked', false);
}
```

Hopefully I am explaining this correctly. I have looked for three days and I am stuck. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 63):

```
$('#checkbox1, #checkbox2').change(function() {
   if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
       // Do some stuff if both boxes are checked...
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked like a charm. I will look into the other solutions when I have more time.

Comment: If this solved your solution you should mark it as the answer to your question.

Comment: You could also use the jQuery add() method, but this will work best in most situations.

Comment: Seems to me it would be easier just to remove the change event and just use the if statement given in this answer. The extra code just isn't needed.

Answer (score 8):

Boolean logic ftw! So I'm pretty sure you're looking for what's known as the exclusive or, or XOR. This means that if just one and only one operand is true, the whole expression will be true. If neither operand is true or if both are true, the whole expression will evaluate as false. The operator for this is `^`. So here's the code (borrowing from Chris as the basic format)...

```
$('#checkbox1, #checkbox2').change(function() {
    if($('#checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
        // Both are checked
    }
    else if($('#checkbox1').is(':checked') ^ $('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
        // Exactly one is checked
    }
});
```

In reality, you only need an OR for the second `if` since we're using an `else if` and the first `if` covers when both are checked. But it's not as cool and obviously can't be used by itself to do the same thing (and is better for minifying *cough cough*).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

I would give the checkboxes a common class. Then use that as the selector and count the checked values. Then if two are checked do something. If one is checked then check the value of that one and do what you need to accordingly.

EDIT: So say for instance you assigned a common class of myCheckBoxes

So you could do the following pseudo code:

```
var myCheckBoxes = $('.myCheckBoxes:checked') //not sure on selector

if (myCheckBoxes.length == 2)
    //do something because both are checked
else if (myCheckBoxes.length == 1)
{
    if (myCheckBoxes.val() == "A")
        // do something because A was checked
    else if (myCheckBoxes.val() == "B")
        // do something because B was checked
}
```

Comment: Assuming `.myCheckBoxes` refers to the checkboxes themselves, you'll need to remove the space from your selector.

Comment: this is a good solution, but it may not the readable. if you dont have a description of what the snippet is trying to do

Answer (score 3):

```
var ids = ['#checkbox1', '#checkbox2'],
    $chx = $(ids.join(',')),
    count = $chx.length;

$chx.on('change', function() {
    if ($chx.filter(':checked').length === count) {
        // do stuff
        console.log('all true');
    }
});
```

If the checkboxes are wrapped by some element:

```
<div class="check-group">
    <label><input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox"> one </label>
    <label><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox"> two </label>
</div>
```

Then the wrapping element can have the event listener:

```
$('.check-group').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        $chx = $this.find('input[type=checkbox]'),
        count = $chx.length;

    if (count === 0) {
        return;
    }

    $this.on('change', function() {
        if (count === $chx.filter(':checked').length) {
            console.log('all checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var check1 = $("#check1");
   var check2 = $("#check2");

   // this method decides what to do when a checkbox is clicked
   var trigger_event = function() {
        if (check1.attr("checked") && check2.attr("checked")) {
            event1();
        }
        else if (check1.attr("checked") && !check2.attr("checked")) {
            event2();
        }
        else if (!check1.attr("checked") && check2.attr("checked")) {
            event3();
        }
   };

   // append event
   check1.click(function() {
       trigger_event();
   });

   check2.click(function() {
      trigger_event();
   });

};
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT everyone! I will try these and post what I used here.

Comment: dont forget to mark as an answer the solution that worked best

Answer (score 2):

I would give both (or as many as you like) the same class='chk_option'. If you are using jQuery, then you could do this:

```
function isSelectedBoth(){
    var result = true;
    $('.chk_option').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
            result=false;
    });
    return result;
}
```

When you are defining the on click events for each simply do this:

```
$('.chk_option').change(function(e){
    if (isSelectedBoth()){
    // do something if both are selected
        alert('both checkboxes are selected');
    }else{
    // do something if not
        alert('You must select both checkboxes');
    }
});
```

You can do it even with smarter function then isSelectedBoth() where it could return something more useful then true/false, like order number of un/checked box, an array of elements un/checked etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. you're using `$('#checkbox1 #checkbox2')` to select the two checkboxes, but without a comma that's an *[“ancestor descendant” selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)* and not a *[multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)*
2. the `is()` operator returns `true` if *at least one* of the selected elements matches the given arguments. So, if you use `if ($('#checkbox1, #checkbox2').is(':checked'))` this is true whenever either one (but not necessarily both) checkboxes are checked

So, in order to do something when *both* checkboxes are checked you need to use `is(':checked')` on both separately, as in [the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3190802/2314737).

Here is a demo showing `is()` behavior

```js
$('input').on('change', function(ev) {
  if ($('#checkbox1, #checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
    console.log("is(':checked') true because at least one is checked");
  } else {
    console.log("is(':checked') not true");
  };
  if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
    console.log("both checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>checkbox1<label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"/>checkbox2</label>
```